# How can I get the search form to be selected automatically?

Tags: css, javascript, html

There is an icon to open the search form on my site, and when it is clicked, the search form opens in full screen. I want the search form to be selected automatically, how can I do that?

Here: https://wisekitten.com/

I'm not using jQuery in my project.

Answer (score 1):

This question is more suited to being asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) as it is not a WordPress specific question, but here's a solution for you anyway:

This makes no assumptions about the code controlling the existing functionality on the site, so there might be other ways that are more practical to hook into this process but for now here is an event listening that listens for a click on the "search button", then after waiting 200 miliseconds, the callback function provided to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) will focus the cursor onto the input field that is shown when the search container overlays the full-screen.

```js
!(function($){
    $(function(){
        $('.search-button').on('click', function(event) {
            setTimeout( function() {
                $('.search-form-input').focus();
            }, 200)
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I'm not using jQuery in my project, can I do it with Pure JS?

Comment: @MuratDinc Yep you can but I see you provided an answer to your problem above. Glad you have it solved. Please accept your answer as the correct solution so this Question gets marked off as solved.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: I did what I wanted with these codes.

```
(function() {
    document.querySelector(".search-button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        setTimeout( function() {
            document.querySelector(".search-form-input").focus();
        }, 200);
    });
})();
```